# capacitor in mosfet

Tags: capacitor, mosfet

what is the the difference between the capacitor in Mosfet ( that is between a conductor and a semiconductor ) and a usual capacitor which is (between 2 conductor), is there any advantage in the mosfet capacitor comparing normal capacitors ? (why in the mosfet, the inside capacitor isn't formed using 2 metal plate)

Comment: What do you mean 'is there any advantage'?

Comment: Normally the capacitor in a power MOSFET is an unfortunate side-effect of making the MOSFET, you have to design driver circuits that have enough power to cope with such an inconvenient load.

Comment: I mean, why in the normal capacitors, a metal and semiconductor aren't used as in a mosfet?

Answer (score 2):

In a monolithic IC, MOS capacitors yield more capacitance per acre of IC real estate than other types because the gate oxide thickness is typically made very thin in the CMOS semiconductor process.

On the other hand, they have a number of non-ideal characteristics such as nonlinearity.

Comment: why in the mosfet, the inside capacitor isn't formed using 2 metal plate ?

Comment: There is no deliberate capacitor in a MOSFET transistor, it's a side effect of putting the metal or polysilicon gate over the semiconductor, with gate oxide insulator between.

Comment: i mean if it was possible, it would be better to create this capacitor effect with 2 metal plates, or with a metal and a semiconductor ?

Comment: If you are trying to make a MOS transistor the point is moot- it has to be Metal-Oxide-Semiconductor to be MOS. If you are trying to make a good capacitor, the metal plates are better.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitance parameters of a MOSFET are functions of Vds and Vgs. So they are much like varicap than a standalone capacitor. Better you examine a datasheet of a MOSFET, they usually include a graph about the capacitance.